# Refactoring - Find a function to add column to postgres query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, refactoring

I have the following query I'm looking to add as a database view in a Rails application:

```
select
  recruiters.full_name as recruiter,
  advisors.advisor as agent,
  sum(case when policies.week_number=1 then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk1,
  sum(case when policies.week_number=2 then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk2,
  sum(case when policies.week_number=3 then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk3,
  sum(case when policies.week_number=4 then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk4,
  sum(policies.premium) as total
from policies
  join advisors on policies.advisor_id=advisors.id
  join recruiters on advisors.recruiter_id=recruiters.id
where policies.current_status='T' or policies.current_status='I'
group by recruiters.full_name, advisors.advisor
```

In the select statement I am currently adding a sum statement one week at a time to create new column (creating repetition in the code).  This would result in the following for a full year:

```
sum(case when policies.week_number=1 then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk1,
sum(case when policies.week_number=2 then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk2,
  ....
  ....
sum(case when policies.week_number=52 then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk52,
sum(case when policies.week_number=53 then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk53
```

The result is as follows:

```
Week 1: 
RECRUITER | AGENT      | WK1      
----------|------------|----------
MC        | DM         | 523.8    
MC        | BO         | 0.0      

Week 2:
RECRUITER | AGENT      | WK1      | WK2     
----------|------------|----------|---------
MC        | DM         | 523.8    | -540.0  
MC        | BO         | 0.0      | 0.0   

....

Week 4:
RECRUITER | AGENT      | WK1      | WK2     | WK3      | WK4      | TOTAL
----------|------------|----------|---------|----------|----------|---------
MC        | DM         | 523.8    | -540.0  | 358.44   | 510.0    | 852.24
MC        | BO         | 0.0      | 0.0     | 1543.72  | 0.0      | 1543.72
```

I'd like to refactor the code with something similar to the following logic:

1. Find the uniq set of available weeks in the data set:

   ```
   => [1,2,3,4]
   ```
2. For each week sum policies.premium for each recruiter / agent pairing. In rails I would try something like this to append select statements to the query:

   ```
   table_columns = []
   [1,2,3,4].each do |i|
     table_columns << sum(case when policies.week_number=#{i} then policies.premium else 0 end) as wk#{i}
   end
   ```

For example, when data for policies.week_number=5 is available, column 'wk5' will be added and so on for all 53 weeks in the year.

Is it possible to create a function in Postgres that could accommodate a refactoring such as this?

FYI..I tried with a cross-tab, but I am also calculating subtotals for the grouping recruiter.

Comment: why don't you use a cross-tab function? you can create a plpgsql function which will generate an sql. Downside is that you will need to run that query from your application.

Comment: Can you post actual schema for tables involved ? otherwise I don't see how from this point you can generate results based on quarter, months and days

Comment: thanks @LongBeard_Boldy i edited the post to provide more clarity.  I tried cross-tab function, but didn't know how to subtotal on a group using cross-tab.  My sql knowledge is limited, so I took this approach instead.  Additionally, I removed the comment about parameterizing the query as its not the goal of the post.

Comment: crosstab will perform much much more faster than , heavy sum and case statements

Answer (score 0):

well, based on that example of yours I did write an plpgsql function which refractors and dynamically builds an sql query based on input variables - in this case: weeks requested.

there is much room to improve that query so it is more easily readable, but what a heck ... this was just a quick cooking .

```
DROP FUNCTION if exists stack_test(integer[]);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stack_test(integer[])
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare 
rec record;
sql text;

select_field_sum text;
core_crostab_1 text;
core_crostab_2 text;
ct_field_list text ;

begin

select_field_sum ='0.0';
core_crostab_1   ='';
core_crostab_2   ='';
ct_field_list    ='';

FOR rec IN select unnest(( $1)) i  order by 1
   loop
   ct_field_list     =  ct_field_list ||',wk' || (rec.i)::text  || ' numeric'  ;
   select_field_sum  =  select_field_sum ||  '+coalesce(wk' || (rec.i)::text|| ',0)' ;   
   end loop;

core_crostab_1  = 'select advisor_id, week_number,sum(premium) premium from policies  where week_number = any ( array['|| array_to_string($1, ',') ||'] ) and policies.current_status=''''T'''' or policies.current_status=''''I'''' group by advisor_id,week_number order by 1,2';
core_crostab_2  = 'select unnest((array['|| array_to_string($1, ',') ||']  )) order by 1';

sql  = 'select *, ('||select_field_sum||') premiumsum  from crosstab('''||core_crostab_1||''', '''||core_crostab_2||''') as ct(advisor_id integer '||  ct_field_list ||') ';
sql = 'select recruiters.full_name as requiter,advisors.advisor ,q1.* from ( '||sql||')q1 left join advisors on(q1.advisor_id= advisors.id )  left join recruiters on (advisors.recruiter_id = recruiters.id) order by 1,2';

return  sql::text;
 end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql volatile
  COST 100;
```